# iTerm2 not pasting newlines for long chunks of code

Tags: clipboard, iterm2

I’m having issues with iTerm2 not pasting newlines when I copy a certain number of lines and paste it into any interpreter. For example, if I copy the code below and paste it into the R interpreter, all the lines are collapsed and it errors out (similarly if I paste the string into the Python interpreter).

It does however work if I paste the string into bash; it also works if I paste it into an interpreter in Terminal.app (and `pbcopy/pbpaste` registers the newlines correctly), so it has to be a problem with iTerm2. Any help is appreciated.

```
gibbs <- function(theta.0, data, burnin=.25*niters, niters=1e3) {
  # Sample using Gibbs.
  #
  # Args:
  #   theta.0: Starting value.
  #   data: list with x and y
  #   burnin: Number of initial samples to throw away.
  #   niters: Number of desired iterations.
  #
  # Returns:
  #   Matrix with (niters-burnin) columns being samples under the target
  #   distribution.
  library(mvtnorm)
  # Declare constants.
  n <- length(data$y)
  X <- cbind(rep(1, length(data$x)), data$x)
  # Initialize output.
  theta.out <- matrix(rep(NA, (n+2)*(burnin+niters)), nrow=n+2)
  # Initialize proposals.
  beta.props <- t(rmvnorm(burnin+niters, mean=rep(0,2), sigma=solve(t(X)%*%X)))
  z.props <- matrix(abs(rnorm(n*(burnin+niters), mean=0, sd=1)), nrow=n)
  z.props[data$y == 0, ] <- -z.props[data$y == 0, ]
  # Initialize parameters.
  beta.old <- theta.0[1:2]
  z.old <- theta.0[3:(n+2)]
  for (i in 1:(burnin+niters)) {
    beta.new <- solve(t(X)%*%X)%*%t(X)%*%z.old + beta.props[, i]
    z.new <- X%*%beta.new + z.props[, i]
    # Save the draw.
    theta.out[, i] <- c(z.new, beta.new)
    beta.old <- beta.new
    z.old <- z.new
  }
  # Remove the burn-in samples.
  theta.out[, -(1:burnin)]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

iTerm2 splits large text into chunks and then sends these chunks with some small delay.
This happens because because iTerm2 has very small delay by default.

To fix large text pasting you can change chunk size and delay options using `defaults` command. Just run commands bellow in your iTerm2:

```
defaults write com.googlecode.iterm2 QuickPasteBytesPerCall -int 1024
defaults write com.googlecode.iterm2 QuickPasteDelayBetweenCalls -float 0.08
```